# Как вывести все файлы в определенной папке ftp сервера С#

Tags: c#, ftp

```
        String url = "ftp:url/file";
        String file = @"C:\file";
        wc.DownloadFile(url, file);
```

код работает, все хорошо. НО. Надо узнать все файлы которые есть в папке, чтобы я мог там например в листбоксе кликнуть и скачать этот файл (важно, чтобы и расширения тоже было видно)

Comment: попробуйте библиотеку FluentFtp, если работаете на windows только и .net framework, есть альтернатива в виде pinvoke

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам подойдет:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace FtpList
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://speedtest.tele2.net");

      //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
      request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

      using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
          using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, true))
          {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В документации к [`FtpWebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) сказано: *Не рекомендуется использовать класс `FtpWebRequest` для новой разработки. Дополнительные сведения и альтернативные варианты `FtpWebRequest` см. в разделе [WebRequest не должен использоваться](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md) на GitHub.*